# Autocomplete jQuery with no results message & could not be submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, submit

First of all I am not good at all with jQuery. I want to achieve two functions at the same time concerning the jQuery autocomplete. The first to show no results found message if there is no any result matching what it has been searched for, and in this case I want to disable the submit input field. I have read a lot and I build some code which is working partially.
I mean if there is no results found the submit button will be disabled but even if the user chose the right suggestion later, the submit button will be still disabled and I don't need it.

**Code**

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#auto" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'scripts/chresults.php',
  response: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) 
            {
                $("#empty-message").text("No ruselts found");
                $(":submit").prop("disabled", !ui.item);
            }
            else 
            {
                $("#empty-message").empty();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#empty-message { float: left; }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="auto" />
        <p id="empty-message"></p>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

[See my test on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYRhE/5/)

I am looking for the most simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    response: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length === 0) {
            $("#empty-message").text("No results found");
            $(":submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
        } else {
            $("#empty-message").empty();
            $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }
});
```